Efficiently drawing a line with alpha value in OpenCV(c++)
I'm seeking a more efficient method to draw a transparent line on an image. With the current OpenCV line functions, the performance is considerably slower than desired. The sluggishness seems to stem from the need to clone and overwrite the image within a loop. Unfortunately, the line function does not accept an alpha value directly, making direct implementation difficult. I prefer to continue using the line function from OpenCV due to its built-in anti-aliasing capability, but I'm open to exploring alternative solutions if available.
The current slow solution
Mat Temp_overlay = inputImage.clone();
line(Temp_overlay, startPoint, endPoint, Scalar(255, 255, 255 /*, 100 Dont take alpha value*/), thickness, LINE_AA);
addWeighted(inputImage, opacity, Temp_overlay , 1.0 - opacity, 0.0, inputImage);

I have come up with some possible solutions.
Possibal solution Nr.1?:
A solution to speed up the code is by implementing something similar to this.
But we will need to find a way to locate the neighboring pixels, so that the thickness can be corrected as well. I believe this will significantly speed up the process.
Mat Temp_overlay = inputImage.clone(); 
line(Temp_overlay, startPoint, endPoint, Scalar(255, 255, 255 /*, 100 Dont take alpha value*/), thickness, LINE_AA); 
addWeighted(inputImage(Rect(startPoint, endPoint)), opacity, 
Temp_overlay(Rect(startPoint, endPoint)), 1.0 - opacity, 0.0, inputImage(Rect(startPoint, endPoint)));

Possibal solution Nr.2?:
Maybe one solution to my problem is to add the alpha channel to the source code for the line function. I have tried to do that, but I can't get it working. And to be fair, the code is a bit too complex for me. At least for now
Here is the source code for the function handling the drawing of lines with anti-aliasing.
//Full function code
static void
LineAA(Mat& img, Point2l pt1, Point2l pt2, const void* color)
{
    int64 dx, dy;
    int ecount, scount = 0;
    int slope;
    int64 ax, ay;
    int64 x_step, y_step;
    int64 i, j;
    int ep_table[9];
    int cb = ((uchar*)color)[0], cg = ((uchar*)color)[1], cr = ((uchar*)color)[2], ca = ((uchar*)color)[3];
    int _cb, _cg, _cr, _ca;
    int nch = img.channels();
    uchar* ptr = img.ptr();
    size_t step = img.step;
    Size2l size(img.size());

    if (!((nch == 1 || nch == 3 || nch == 4) && img.depth() == CV_8U))
    {
        Line(img, Point((int)(pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT), (int)(pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT)), Point((int)(pt2.x >> XY_SHIFT), (int)(pt2.y >> XY_SHIFT)), color);
        return;
    }

    pt1.x -= XY_ONE * 2;
    pt1.y -= XY_ONE * 2;
    pt2.x -= XY_ONE * 2;
    pt2.y -= XY_ONE * 2;
    ptr += img.step * 2 + 2 * nch;

    size.width = ((size.width - 5) << XY_SHIFT) + 1;
    size.height = ((size.height - 5) << XY_SHIFT) + 1;

    if (!clipLine(size, pt1, pt2))
        return;

    dx = pt2.x - pt1.x;
    dy = pt2.y - pt1.y;

    j = dx < 0 ? -1 : 0;
    ax = (dx ^ j) - j;
    i = dy < 0 ? -1 : 0;
    ay = (dy ^ i) - i;

    if (ax > ay)
    {
        /*Goes here*/
        dy = (dy ^ j) - j;
        pt1.x ^= pt2.x & j;
        pt2.x ^= pt1.x & j;
        pt1.x ^= pt2.x & j;
        pt1.y ^= pt2.y & j;
        pt2.y ^= pt1.y & j;
        pt1.y ^= pt2.y & j;

        x_step = XY_ONE;
        y_step = (dy << XY_SHIFT) / (ax | 1);
        pt2.x += XY_ONE;
        ecount = (int)((pt2.x >> XY_SHIFT) - (pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT));
        j = -(pt1.x & (XY_ONE - 1));
        pt1.y += ((y_step * j) >> XY_SHIFT) + (XY_ONE >> 1);
        slope = (y_step >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 0x3f;
        slope ^= (y_step < 0 ? 0x3f : 0);

        /* Get 4-bit fractions for end-point adjustments */
        i = (pt1.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
        j = (pt2.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
    }
    else
    {
        dx = (dx ^ i) - i;
        pt1.x ^= pt2.x & i;
        pt2.x ^= pt1.x & i;
        pt1.x ^= pt2.x & i;
        pt1.y ^= pt2.y & i;
        pt2.y ^= pt1.y & i;
        pt1.y ^= pt2.y & i;

        x_step = (dx << XY_SHIFT) / (ay | 1);
        y_step = XY_ONE;
        pt2.y += XY_ONE;
        ecount = (int)((pt2.y >> XY_SHIFT) - (pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT));
        j = -(pt1.y & (XY_ONE - 1));
        pt1.x += ((x_step * j) >> XY_SHIFT) + (XY_ONE >> 1);
        slope = (x_step >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 0x3f;
        slope ^= (x_step < 0 ? 0x3f : 0);

        /* Get 4-bit fractions for end-point adjustments */
        i = (pt1.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
        j = (pt2.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
    }

    slope = (slope & 0x20) ? 0x100 : SlopeCorrTable[slope];

    /* Calc end point correction table */
    {
        int t0 = slope << 7;
        int t1 = ((0x78 - (int)i) | 4) * slope;
        int t2 = ((int)j | 4) * slope;

        ep_table[0] = 0;
        ep_table[8] = slope;
        ep_table[1] = ep_table[3] = ((((j - i) & 0x78) | 4) * slope >> 8) & 0x1ff;
        ep_table[2] = (t1 >> 8) & 0x1ff;
        ep_table[4] = ((((j - i) + 0x80) | 4) * slope >> 8) & 0x1ff;
        ep_table[5] = ((t1 + t0) >> 8) & 0x1ff;
        ep_table[6] = (t2 >> 8) & 0x1ff;
        ep_table[7] = ((t2 + t0) >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    }

    if (nch == 3)
    {
#define  ICV_PUT_POINT()            \
        {                                   \
            _cb = tptr[0];                  \
            _cb += ((cb - _cb)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            _cg = tptr[1];                  \
            _cg += ((cg - _cg)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            _cr = tptr[2];                  \
            _cr += ((cr - _cr)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            tptr[0] = (uchar)_cb;           \
            tptr[1] = (uchar)_cg;           \
            tptr[2] = (uchar)_cr;           \
        }
        if (ax > ay)
        {
            ptr += (pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) * 3;

            while (ecount >= 0)
            {
                uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * step;

                int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                    (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
                int a, dist = (pt1.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += step;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += step;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                pt1.y += y_step;
                ptr += 3;
                scount++;
                ecount--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ptr += (pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) * step;

            while (ecount >= 0)
            {
                uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * 3;

                int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                    (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
                int a, dist = (pt1.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += 3;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += 3;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                pt1.x += x_step;
                ptr += step;
                scount++;
                ecount--;
            }
        }
#undef ICV_PUT_POINT
    }
    else if (nch == 1)
    {
#define  ICV_PUT_POINT()            \
        {                                   \
            _cb = tptr[0];                  \
            _cb += ((cb - _cb)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            tptr[0] = (uchar)_cb;           \
        }

        if (ax > ay)
        {
            ptr += (pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT);

            while (ecount >= 0)
            {
                uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * step;

                int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                    (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
                int a, dist = (pt1.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += step;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += step;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                pt1.y += y_step;
                ptr++;
                scount++;
                ecount--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ptr += (pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) * step;

            while (ecount >= 0)
            {
                uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) - 1);

                int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                    (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
                int a, dist = (pt1.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr++;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr++;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                pt1.x += x_step;
                ptr += step;
                scount++;
                ecount--;
            }
        }
#undef ICV_PUT_POINT
    }
    else
    {

         //color
#define  ICV_PUT_POINT()            \
        {                                   \
            _cb = tptr[0];                  \
            _cb += ((cb - _cb)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            _cg = tptr[1];                  \
            _cg += ((cg - _cg)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            _cr = tptr[2];                  \
            _cr += ((cr - _cr)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            _ca = tptr[3];                  \
            _ca += ((ca - _ca)*a + 127)>> 8;\
            tptr[0] = (uchar)_cb;           \
            tptr[1] = (uchar)_cg;           \
            tptr[2] = (uchar)_cr;           \
            tptr[3] = (uchar)_ca;           \
        }
        if (ax > ay)
        {
            /*Goes here*/
            ptr += (pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) * 4;

            while (ecount >= 0)
            {
                /*Goes here*/
                uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * step;

                int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                    (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
                int a, dist = (pt1.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += step;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += step;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                pt1.y += y_step;
                ptr += 4;
                scount++;
                ecount--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ptr += (pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) * step;

            while (ecount >= 0)
            {
                uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * 4;

                int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                    (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
                int a, dist = (pt1.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += 4;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                tptr += 4;
                a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
                ICV_PUT_POINT();
                ICV_PUT_POINT();

                pt1.x += x_step;
                ptr += step;
                scount++;
                ecount--;
            }
        }
#undef ICV_PUT_POINT
    }
}

Update 14.05.24
I have managed to create a solution based on "Possible solution Nr.2?:". And i will say the speed is good. But will keep this question open a bit longer incase if someone have an even better solution.
I also created "Possible solution Nr.1?:". That was still to slow.
It was around 3x the speed of "The current slow solution" but still very slow.
Speedtest drawing 1000 lines =
Normal line without alpha       :   0.0763387     seconds,
Original solution               : 745.123         seconds,
Custom line function with alpha :   0.291911      seconds.
//Modified function from OpenCV LineAA
bool ScalarToRawData(const Scalar& s, void* _buf, int type, int unroll_to)
{
    int i, depth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(type), cn = CV_MAT_CN(type);
    CV_Assert(cn <= 4);
    switch (depth)
    {
    case CV_8U:
    {
        uchar* buf = (uchar*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<uchar>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
    }
    break;
    case CV_8S:
    {
        schar* buf = (schar*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<schar>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
    }
    break;
    case CV_16U:
    {
        ushort* buf = (ushort*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<ushort>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
    }
    break;
    case CV_16S:
    {
        short* buf = (short*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<short>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
    }
    break;
    case CV_32S:
    {
        int* buf = (int*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<int>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
    }
    break;
    case CV_32F:
    {
        float* buf = (float*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<float>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
    }
    break;
    case CV_64F:
    {
        double* buf = (double*)_buf;
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i++)
            buf[i] = saturate_cast<double>(s.val[i]);
        for (; i < unroll_to; i++)
            buf[i] = buf[i - cn];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        //CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "");
        cout << "!ERROR!: CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "");" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    }
    return true;
}

/*
Function CustomLineAntiAliased Info :
-4 channel images only
-Line Thickness = 1 pixel
*/
bool CustomLineAntiAliased(InputOutputArray _img, Point _pt1, Point _pt2, const Scalar& S_Color, float Opacity/*Range : 0-1*/, int shift/*Number of fractional bits in the point coordinates. = normaly 0*/)
{
    Point2l pt1 = _pt1;
    Point2l pt2 = _pt2;
    Mat img = _img.getMat();

double color[4];
if (!ScalarToRawData(S_Color, color, img.type(), 0))
{
    return false;
}

if (!(0 <= shift && shift <= XY_SHIFT))
    return false;

pt1.x <<= XY_SHIFT - shift;
pt1.y <<= XY_SHIFT - shift;
pt2.x <<= XY_SHIFT - shift;
pt2.y <<= XY_SHIFT - shift;

int64 dx, dy;
int ecount, scount = 0;
int slope;
int64 ax, ay;
int64 x_step, y_step;
int64 i, j;
int ep_table[9];
int cb = ((uchar*)color)[0], cg = ((uchar*)color)[1], cr = ((uchar*)color)[2], ca = ((uchar*)color)[3];
int _cb, _cg, _cr, _ca;
int nch = img.channels();
uchar* ptr = img.ptr();
size_t step = img.step;
Size2l size(img.size());

if (!((nch == 4) && img.depth() == CV_8U))
{
    return false;
}

pt1.x -= XY_ONE * 2;
pt1.y -= XY_ONE * 2;
pt2.x -= XY_ONE * 2;
pt2.y -= XY_ONE * 2;
ptr += img.step * 2 + 2 * nch;

size.width = ((size.width - 5) << XY_SHIFT) + 1;
size.height = ((size.height - 5) << XY_SHIFT) + 1;

if (!clipLine(size, pt1, pt2))
    return false;

dx = pt2.x - pt1.x;
dy = pt2.y - pt1.y;

j = dx < 0 ? -1 : 0;
ax = (dx ^ j) - j;
i = dy < 0 ? -1 : 0;
ay = (dy ^ i) - i;

if (ax > ay)
{
    dy = (dy ^ j) - j;
    pt1.x ^= pt2.x & j;
    pt2.x ^= pt1.x & j;
    pt1.x ^= pt2.x & j;
    pt1.y ^= pt2.y & j;
    pt2.y ^= pt1.y & j;
    pt1.y ^= pt2.y & j;

    x_step = XY_ONE;
    y_step = (dy << XY_SHIFT) / (ax | 1);
    pt2.x += XY_ONE;
    ecount = (int)((pt2.x >> XY_SHIFT) - (pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT));
    j = -(pt1.x & (XY_ONE - 1));
    pt1.y += ((y_step * j) >> XY_SHIFT) + (XY_ONE >> 1);
    slope = (y_step >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 0x3f;
    slope ^= (y_step < 0 ? 0x3f : 0);

    /* Get 4-bit fractions for end-point adjustments */
    i = (pt1.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
    j = (pt2.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
}
else
{
    dx = (dx ^ i) - i;
    pt1.x ^= pt2.x & i;
    pt2.x ^= pt1.x & i;
    pt1.x ^= pt2.x & i;
    pt1.y ^= pt2.y & i;
    pt2.y ^= pt1.y & i;
    pt1.y ^= pt2.y & i;

    x_step = (dx << XY_SHIFT) / (ay | 1);
    y_step = XY_ONE;
    pt2.y += XY_ONE;
    ecount = (int)((pt2.y >> XY_SHIFT) - (pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT));
    j = -(pt1.y & (XY_ONE - 1));
    pt1.x += ((x_step * j) >> XY_SHIFT) + (XY_ONE >> 1);
    slope = (x_step >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 0x3f;
    slope ^= (x_step < 0 ? 0x3f : 0);

    /* Get 4-bit fractions for end-point adjustments */
    i = (pt1.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
    j = (pt2.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 7)) & 0x78;
}

slope = (slope & 0x20) ? 0x100 : SlopeCorrTable[slope];

/* Calc end point correction table */
{
    int t0 = slope << 7;
    int t1 = ((0x78 - (int)i) | 4) * slope;
    int t2 = ((int)j | 4) * slope;

    ep_table[0] = 0;
    ep_table[8] = slope;
    ep_table[1] = ep_table[3] = ((((j - i) & 0x78) | 4) * slope >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    ep_table[2] = (t1 >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    ep_table[4] = ((((j - i) + 0x80) | 4) * slope >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    ep_table[5] = ((t1 + t0) >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    ep_table[6] = (t2 >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    ep_table[7] = ((t2 + t0) >> 8) & 0x1ff;
}

    if (ax > ay)
    {
       
        ptr += (pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) * 4;

        while (ecount >= 0)
        {
            
            uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * step;

            int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
            int a, dist = (pt1.y >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

            a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;
            
            //If you want to store coordinates, you can do this : cv::Point2i Coordinates = cv::Point2i((tptr - img.data) % img.step / img.elemSize(), (tptr - img.data) / img.step); 
            _cb = tptr[0];
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cg = tptr[1];
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cr = tptr[2];
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _ca = tptr[3];
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;

            tptr[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[0] * Opacity + _cb * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[1] * Opacity + _cg * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[2] * Opacity + _cr * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[3] * Opacity + _ca * (1.0 - Opacity));

            

            tptr += step;
            a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
            _cb = tptr[0];
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cg = tptr[1];
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cr = tptr[2];
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _ca = tptr[3];
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;

            tptr[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[0] * Opacity + _cb * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[1] * Opacity + _cg * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[2] * Opacity + _cr * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[3] * Opacity + _ca * (1.0 - Opacity));

            tptr += step;
            a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;

            _cb = tptr[0];
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cg = tptr[1];
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cr = tptr[2];
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _ca = tptr[3];
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;

            tptr[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[0] * Opacity + _cb * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[1] * Opacity + _cg * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[2] * Opacity + _cr * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[3] * Opacity + _ca * (1.0 - Opacity));


            pt1.y += y_step;
            ptr += 4;
            scount++;
            ecount--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ptr += (pt1.y >> XY_SHIFT) * step;

        while (ecount >= 0)
        {
            uchar* tptr = ptr + ((pt1.x >> XY_SHIFT) - 1) * 4;

            int ep_corr = ep_table[(((scount >= 2) + 1) & (scount | 2)) * 3 +
                (((ecount >= 2) + 1) & (ecount | 2))];
            int a, dist = (pt1.x >> (XY_SHIFT - 5)) & 31;

            a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist + 32] >> 8) & 0xff;

            _cb = tptr[0];
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cg = tptr[1];
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cr = tptr[2];
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _ca = tptr[3];
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;

            tptr[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[0] * Opacity + _cb * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[1] * Opacity + _cg * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[2] * Opacity + _cr * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[3] * Opacity + _ca * (1.0 - Opacity));


            tptr += 4;
            a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
            
            _cb = tptr[0];
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cg = tptr[1];
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cr = tptr[2];
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _ca = tptr[3];
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;

            tptr[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[0] * Opacity + _cb * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[1] * Opacity + _cg * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[2] * Opacity + _cr * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[3] * Opacity + _ca * (1.0 - Opacity));

            tptr += 4;
            a = (ep_corr * FilterTable[63 - dist] >> 8) & 0xff;
           
            _cb = tptr[0];
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cb += ((cb - _cb) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cg = tptr[1];
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cg += ((cg - _cg) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _cr = tptr[2];
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _cr += ((cr - _cr) * a + 127) >> 8;

            _ca = tptr[3];
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;
            _ca += ((ca - _ca) * a + 127) >> 8;

            tptr[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[0] * Opacity + _cb * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[1] * Opacity + _cg * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[2] * Opacity + _cr * (1.0 - Opacity));
            tptr[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(tptr[3] * Opacity + _ca * (1.0 - Opacity));

            pt1.x += x_step;
            ptr += step;
            scount++;
            ecount--;
        }
    }

 return true;

}

You can use the cv::LineIterator to get the line points. For each point you can set the color value you need.  This will be a lot faster.

@Miki Thats going to have the same problem as "Possible solution Nr.1".
When the thickness is more than 1 pixel. And i need anti-aliasing.
Thank you for the reply :)

Because as you can see. If you dont get a answer the 1/2 day. The chance of getting an answer is almost 0%. Because it disappears in the deep sea of questions... :( @beaker

@Mike Have updated post :)

@beaker Have updated post :)

@beaker yes, but don't get how that helps me situation? Place clarify :) Thanks for replying

@beaker
If refering to cv2.line(color=(0, 0, 200, 255)). atleast on the c++ version. Alpha isn't supported.But hopefully one day thay add it to opencv. It is highly requested problem, that need to be solved/added...

@beaker If so. Please create an answer and prove it. Draw a transparent line on top of an image :)

@beaker https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2
Note
The functions do not support alpha-transparency when the target image is 4-channel. In this case, the color[3] is simply copied to the repainted pixels. Thus, if you want to paint semi-transparent shapes, you can paint them in a separate buffer and then blend it with the main image.

@beaker I got it working :) Was some stupid mistake. missed this coversion Point2l pt1 = _pt1; Point2l pt2 = _pt2. You can see the code now.....
